# urllib produces garbled output under windows?

Tags: python, windows, urllib

I download an image from the web under linux (debian) without problems, using the code snippet below. When I run the exact same code in windows, the resulting image is garbled. What is the problem?

```
import urllib, os
url = "http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/10.1.jpg"
contents = urllib.urlopen (url).read()
fn = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "winimagetest")
fh = open(fn, "w");fh.write(contents);fh.close()
```

The target system is Windows 7, 64 bit, and the python installation is 32 bit. (This does not matter, the same garbled output happens if python is 64 bit).

I've uploaded the garbled [image](http://www.filetolink.com/e3fb6aeffb):

Comment: urllib is deprecated I think. You should check out [requests](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python-requests.org%2Fen%2Flatest%2Findex.html). Not that it would lead you to the source of the bug here, just a suggestion.

Comment: My first try would be to make sure you are opening the file for writing in binary format, which I believe is **not** the default on windows.  `open(fn, "wb")`

Comment: What a trivial thing Opening as binary solved the issue. @sberry, could you please add your answer so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows, you need to open the file in binary mode since Windows distinguishes between binary and text files.  It works on Linux as-is because Linux makes no such distinction.

Change the line

```
fh = open(fn, "w")
```

to

```
fh = open(fn, "wb")
```

You may also want to consider doing the following:

```
with open(fn, "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(contents)
```

As it will handle closing the file for you in case of any type of exception.

Comment: I originally wrote a one-line python (which can not include complex statements like `with`) so I could easily copy to the windows cmd, but that turned out too unreadable in the question, so I split each line. But thanks for your answer.